# Accessibilty shortcut to center the mouse for visually impaired?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, cursor, accessibility

For a  visually impaired person with a very narrow field of vision it can be difficult to locate the mouse.

*Imagine someone with glaucoma, they are [looking through a straw](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4206382/figure/F1/), so they have to scan the screen (or a sentence character by character).*

Is there a keyboard shortcut to *center* the cursor on the screen, or any other sensible place like *left top*?

Preferable a solution that works in both Wayland and X11 in Ubuntu 22.04.

*Updated*

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no keyboard shortcut or any other provision to return the mouse cursor to a standard position.

You could create a shortcut key that centers the mouse cursor yourself using a keyboard/mouse simulation tool. `ydotool` works on both Xorg and Wayland. A shortcut key could then be assigned that invokes `ydotool` to position the mouse cursor on the center of the screen.

Note that there is different feature in Accessibility that may fit the purpose: you can highlight the cursor so it can easily be seen where it currently is by pressing a shortcut key (by default the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key). You can turn that on under "Settings" - "Accessibility" - "Pointing & Clicking": "Locate Pointer". *Caveat* for this feature to work, "Reduce Animations" under "Accessibility" - "Seeing" may *not* be turned of.

Comment: Thx, I'm aware of the locate cursor function, but that does not really help a person with a narrow visual field (looking through a straw)

Comment: That is why I first answered how it could be done, before pointing to the locate cursor function.

Comment: Yes, ydotool is a good tip, something like that crossed my mind.