# How to set the cursor location in a Gnome Shell Extension?

Tags: mouse, gnome-shell-extension, accessibility

I'm trying to set my first steps in a Gnome Extension to help visually impaired people to find the cursor by moving to it a fixed location.

As it seems there is [no easy way to do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483203/accessibilty-shortcut-to-center-the-mouse-for-visually-impaired).

I have a [hacked a rather simple solution](https://dev.webonomic.nl/improving-accessibility-in-ubuntu-for-the-visually-impaired-with-a-narrow-field-of-vision) with [dotool](https://sr.ht/%7Egeb/dotool/), but that seems to be overkill, and it's not that trivial to install (not in the debs).

I'm able to get the mouse location in a test extension by:

```
....
let [mouse_x, mouse_y, mask] = global.get_pointer();
....
```

But, alas, global.set_pointer(30,20) is not a function.

Is there a way to do this, (and where can I find the docs for the `global` object?)

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474276/can-gnome-shell-extensions-move-the-pointer-if-so-how

Comment: Thx again, I already saw that post, but I considered that outdated. This feeling is creeping up [gnome-shell-breaks-catastrophically-every-few-month] ;)
I think I'll try discourse.gnome.org

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer you at moment. However, myself went through hard path to where to reach documentation about Gnome API's and its different components for extensions development.

- Most Gnome documentation related to GJS which is the core for Gnome-Shell Extensions are hosted here: https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/
- Documentation is searchable and can be set to work offline. So doc entry of `global.get_pointer()` method is here: [https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell12~12/shell.global#method-get_pointer](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell12%7E12/shell.global#method-get_pointer)
- Few things I advise you to watch out for:

  1. Which Gnome version? Gnome is changing fast
  2. Which API version? Is it not always easy to figure current running Gnome-shell corresponds to which API/Lib versions
  3. Display Back-end (Wayland, X11)? Keyboard and Mouse is handled differently at lower level (Like GDK).
  4. Mutter has its own internal copy of the Clutter library with different API than the standalone Clutter library (which is deprecated). Expect few methods are not available in both: Standalone GJS apps, Gnome-shell Extensions.